# tf/tutorials demo problem ros-electric

Tags: ros, ros-tutorials, ros-electric, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All:

I can't get the turtle_tf demo to work based on the following link: [tf/Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf)

This is the error I get when I do **roslaunch turtle_tf turtle_tf_demo.launch**:

```
Use arrow keys to move the turtle.
process[turtle2_tf_broadcaster-5]: started with pid [9096]
process[turtle_pointer-6]: started with pid [9101]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/geometry_tutorials/turtle_tf/node/turtle_tf_listener.py", line 57, in <module>
(trans,rot) = listener.lookupTransform('/turtle2', '/turtle1', rospy.Time())
tf.ExtrapolationException: Lookup would require extrapolation at time 1321729575.578088045, but only time 1321729575.578494072 is in the buffer, when looking up transform from frame [/turtle1] to frame [/turtle2]
[turtle_pointer-6] process has died [pid 9101, exit code 1].
log files: /home/adith/.ros/log/8cffc6c6-12e1-11e1-81b9-0026829e5a54/turtle_pointer-6*.log
```

Another post mentions this same [problem](http://answers.ros.org/question/2187/turtlesim-tf)
but they were using diamondback. How do I resolve this on electric?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12024/tf/tutorials-demo-problem-ros-electric/) by [asrinivasan31](https://answers.ros.org/users/1262/asrinivasan31/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2011-11-19

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add tf.ExtrapolationException to the list of exceptions to be discarded when making the call to tf.lookupTransform. New code will look like this,

```
    try:
        (trans,rot) = listener.lookupTransform('/turtle2', '/turtle1', rospy.Time())
    except (tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException, tf.ExtrapolationException):
        continue
```

---

Originally posted by [Anand B](https://answers.ros.org/users/1889/anand-b/) with karma: 46 on 2012-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kawamura Masaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/21010/kawamura-masaya/) on 2014-12-02**:
Hi, I found we still need this Patch for hydro

**Comment by [Kawamura Masaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/21010/kawamura-masaya/) on 2014-12-02**:
created PR -> https://github.com/ros/geometry_tutorials/pull/16